# Run Android Studio on Pentium 4 machine

Tags: android-studio

I have a Pentium 4 machine with 2.26 Ghz with 2gb RAM.

I would like to use it without emulator.

I have installed it on my system but it loads too slow.

Is there a way to make it a little fast.

Answer (score 0):

- **Software area:**

  - Uninstall unwanted software.
  - If possible re-install your operating system.
- **Hardware area:**

  - Add more RAM ( minimum 4GB )
  - Free up your hard drive.